# Select DayOfWeek Last Week

Tags: c#

How can I get the the date of `DayOfWeek` last week?

for example

I want to select Sunday June 23 as `DayOfWeek`?

I can only get is the `DayOfWeek` of this week.

here's my code

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;

while (today.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    today = today.AddDays(-1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
DayOfWeek dayToFind = DayOfWeek.Sunday;
today.AddDays(-1 * (int)today.DayOfWeek).AddDays(-7).AddDays((int)dayToFind);
```

The first AddDays backs up to the start of *this* week, then AddDays(-7) backs up to the start of *last* week, then the third AddDays advances to the day you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you! I need to wait for 4 minutes to accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
int difference = today.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Sunday;
DateTime lastSunday = today.AddDays(-difference).AddDays(-(7 * 1));
                                                          //   ^ number of weeks to remove
```

This basically says, "Go to the start of the week, then remove another 7 days".

Comment: Incidentally, subtracting DayOfWeek.Sunday isn't necessary since it's value is 0.

Comment: True, but the idea was to show how you might go back to say.. Monday.

Comment: But that is irrelevant.  You might as well write `today.DayOfWeek - 0` and this has nothing to do with how to get to Monday or any day other than Sunday.

Comment: Oh nevermind - I understand what you are doing.  You mean to change DayOfWeek.Sunday to the day that you are searching.  It's good.

Comment: You made me double and triple-read what I had written.. but yes, that's the idea :)

Comment: It might be more clear if you extracted that to a variable, as I did in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the DateTime object to a specific date by creating it with an initial date value. If you want it to be based from today rather than a specified date, just subtract a week.